# Сравнение двух строчек python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки

У меня есть 2 товара.

Первый: Творог Простоквашино 9%

Второй: Творог 9%, «Простоквашино», 220 г, Россия

Как сравнить их между собой так, чтобы программа поняла, что это два одинаковых товара?

Comment: А откуда вывод, что одинаковые? Вдруг у первого подразумевается 50г?

Comment: @andreymal Мне надо чтобы он понял, что это творог и то что это Простоквашино. ну и процентовку

Comment: Боюсь, универсального и надёжного решения не получится

Comment: @andreymal ну или как нибудь можно сделать так, чтобы он понял что на 70 или 80 процентов совпадает. Значит они одинаковые

Comment: @andreymal У меня база товаров одного магазина и база товаров другого магазина. Я должен сравнить товары, и в случае нахождения одинаковых вытянуть из базы ссылки на товары и сделать вот так "ссылка на 1 = ссылка на 2"

Comment: @andreymal В базах около 10 000 товаров

Comment: И неужели в этих базах нет чего-то более надёжного вроде штрих-кода?

Comment: Я парсировал только название и ссылку на него

Comment: @andreymal И мне надо по двум названиям понять одинаковы товары или нет

Comment: Перепарсируйте со штрих-кодом)

Comment: @andreymal Я парсировал по главной странице, там только укороченная карточка, Название, Картинка, и ссылка на него. Если я буду переходить на каждый товар. У меня время уйдёт больше.

Comment: @andreymal На карточке(расширенной) нет штрих кода

Comment: @МаксимХалин, это называется «нечёткое сравнение» (*fuzzy comparison*) алгоритмов есть несколько, как и их реализаций на питоне; все они вероятностные, так что не факт что какой-то сходу даст хороший результат на твоих данных... для обзора по теме прошу в гугл...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Спасибо. Посижу подумаю Как можно с ней поработать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для первого приближения я могу предложить что-нибудь такое:

```
import re

str1 = 'Творог Простоквашино 9%'
str2 = 'Творог 9%, «Простоквашино», 220 г, Россия'

threshold = 1 #чем выше значение, тем менее похоже строки будут считаться похожими
set1 = set(re.split(r"\W+", str1))
set2 = set(re.split(r"\W+", str2))
cmp=list(set1&set2)

if abs(len(cmp)- min(len(set1), len(set2))) <= threshold:
    print ("Строки подозрительно похожи")
```

В моем примере эти две строки будут "подозрительно похожими".

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "Творог Простоквашино 9%"
s2 = "Творог 9%, «Простоквашино», 220 г, Россия"
s = s.lower()
s2 = s2.lower()
lst = s.split()
check = len(lst)
for st in lst:
    if s2.find(st) != -1:
        check = check - 1
    else:
        print('Строки разные')
if check == 0:
    print('Строки одинаковые')
```

Протестировал, когда появилась возможность - поправил. Приношу извинения за изначальный кривой код. Этот должен работать со всеми подобными строками.

Ну и добавлю это же, но в виде функции:

```
def check_strings(s, s2):
    s = s.lower()
    s2 = s2.lower()
    lst = s.split()
    check = len(lst)
    for st in lst:
        if s2.find(st) != -1:
            check = check - 1
        else:
            print('Строки разные')
    if check == 0:
        print('Строки одинаковые')
```

Answer (score 1):

По сути второй товар от первого отличается уточнением, а у того и у того есть тип "творог 9%", можешь реализовать функцию, которая будет искать в первом тип товара, например тот же творог, а затем привязанную к нему характеристику "9%", и если характеристики совпадают, то товары одинаковые. Условие не совсем точное, это могут быть не одинаковые товары, так как в первом товаре нет уточнения, вдруг он не 220 г, а пол литра? Код сам пиши, мысль я тебе дал, если не понимаешь о чём я сказал - продолжай учить основы программирования python.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

# Ваши товары
val = """
Первый: Творог Простоквашино 9%
Второй: Творог 9%, 'Простоквашино', 220 г, Россия
Второй: Творог 5%, 'Хороший', 220 г, Россия
Второй: Творог 1%, , Россия , ТМ Хороший
Первый: Сметана Простоквашино 19%
"""

# Делаем список, где каждый элемент будет содержать ['Наименование товара','Торговая марка']
tovars = [['Творог','Простоквашино'], ['Творог','Хороший'], ['Творог','Хороший']]

# Дальше делайте то, что вам надо
# Например сделать выборку по первому элементу справочника `tovars[0] = ['Творог','Простоквашино']`

pp( [ i for i in val.split('\n')  if tovars[0][0] in i and tovars[0][1] in i] )

['Первый: Творог Простоквашино 9%',
 "Второй: Творог 9%, 'Простоквашино', 220 г, Россия"]
```